Mount error Ceph storage
I'm trying to mount CephFS to my host.
mount -t ceph -o name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/admin.secret  192.168.1.88:/exports/data/ /rhev/data-center/mnt/

But I get an error:
mount error 2 = No such file or directory

This directory is definitely present.
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root  4096 окт 17 17:00 exports

Ceph info:
[root@host1 /]# ceph -s
cluster:
  id:     4ef9a8f9-7ac2-4617-a5d8-c450d857973c
  health: HEALTH_WARN
        mons are allowing insecure global_id reclaim
        clock skew detected on mon.host2, mon.host3

services:
  mon: 3 daemons, quorum host1,host2,host3 (age 2h)
  mgr: host1.home.dom(active, since 5h)
  mds: 1/1 daemons up
  osd: 3 osds: 3 up (since 5h), 3 in (since 25h)

data:
  volumes: 1/1 healthy
  pools:   3 pools, 81 pgs
  objects: 24 objects, 594 KiB
  usage:   107 MiB used, 150 GiB / 150 GiB avail
  pgs:     81 active+clean

[root@host1 /]# systemctl status ceph-mds.target
● ceph-mds.target - ceph target allowing to start/stop all ceph-mds@.service instances at once
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ceph-mds.target; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active since Thu 2024-10-17 13:22:28 MSK; 5h 30min ago


What are the permissions, ownership, mount status of each of the parent directories? Ditto for /etc/ceph/admin.secret. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

So just to be clear, when you created the filesystem, you mounted the root directory / as admin user, then you created the directory structure /exports/data? Because you only show /exports but not the entire path /exports/data.
